# ASP.NET MVC 3 ClientValidationEnabled is not posting back to the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on an MVC 3 project and i am having issue with enabling client side validation.

In my master layout I have the following

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When i turn on client side validation in root web.config

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

then on submitting the form, the validation works but if i enter valid values on the form and submit it, it never gets posted back to the server as if the validation is failing on the client side. I can see in firebug/fiddler that nothing is posting back. Any idea?

Regards,
Nabeel

Comment: You question says it does not postback. what do you mean by "it does get posted back to the server as if the validation is failing on the client side"? Does it postback or does it not?

Comment: never mind. It was the hidden model Id field that was empty and it was complaining about it. After setting the @Html.ValidationSummary(false) to false I get to see that error. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hi mare. I meant it does not get posted to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is thought from my experience.

I experienced similar kind of situation, later found that one of the validation in the page is failing which is not explicit.

- Make sure that after you entered the input, all the input satisfy the validation
- Make sure that you have validation error message for each unique scenarios